# Why do we need to leave an empty cell in a circular queue to determine whether it is empty or not?

Tags: c, data-structures

I just learned about circular queues in class and I'm still confused, I know that without the empty cell we wouldn't be able to distinguish between an empty queue and a a queue with one element, but why ?
I used f.h for prototypes and f.c as implementation:
f.h:

```c
#define n 50
struct queue
{
    int key[n];
    unsigned head;
    unsigned tail;
};
void cree(struct queue *);
unsigned empty(struct queue);
int first(struct queue);
void enqueue(int, struct queue *);
void dequeue(struct queue *);
```

then f.c:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include "f.h"
void cree(struct queue *q)
{
    q->head = 0;
    q->tail = 0;
}
unsigned empty(struct queue q)
{
    return (q.head == q.tail);
}
int first(struct queue q)
{
    unsigned i;
    assert(!empty(q));
    i = q.head + 1;
    if(i>n-1)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    return(q.key[i]);
}
void enqueue(int x, struct queue *q)
{
    q->tail++;
    if(q->tail>n-1)
    {
        q->tail = 0;
    }
    assert(q->head != q->head);
    q->key[q->tail] = x;
}
void dequeue(struct queue *q)
{
    assert(!empty(*q));
    q->head++;
    if(q->head>n-1)
    {
        q->head =0 ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with the code we learnt, I still have no idea how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this a little bit wrong in 2 ways.  The first way is that the confusion is between an empty queue and a *full* queue, not a queue with 1 element.  Keeping one cell empty changes what it means to be "full".

So, given a circular queue, how do you determine how many elements it has in it?

You would like to write `size = (end_position - start_position) % array_length`.  In fact, the `%` operator probably doesn't work like you want in your language, though, so you'll write  `size = (array_length + end_position - start_position) % array_length`

If the queue is empty, you get `size == 0`, which is what you want.  If the queue has `array_length` elements in it, though, you also get `size == 0`, which is wrong.  You can fix that by ensuring that the number of elements is always *less* than the array length.

The other way you have this wrong is the "wouldn't be able to" part.  It's almost always wrong to say that.  If you store `start_position` and `size`, for example, instead of `start_position` and `end_position`, then it's easy to distinguish full from empty, and you can put `array_length` elements in your queue.

Comment: I updated the question, can you tell me where what you said happens ?

Comment: It happens in `empty()`